# Filter for not empty

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, filter

Newbie to scripting here...

I've successfully used a script based on this post:
[Google Script for Sheets: Set multiple filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51448537/google-script-for-sheets-set-multiple-filters)

How may I adjust the code to set the filter to prevent all non-blank entries for appearing?  I've tried variations of `Null, "", BLANK` with no success.

```
function setFilters() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName("Project Tracker");
  var rang = sh.getDataRange();
  var filtercriteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().setHiddenValues(["Completed","Cancelled"]).build();//used Cancelled NOT Canceled; Create criteria with two hidden values
  var filter = rang.getFilter() || rang.createFilter();// getFilter already available or create  a new one
  filter.setColumnFilterCriteria(2, filtercriteria);//set the criteria against Col2 (B column)
}
```

Most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> **Answer**: use single quotes for the hidden values.

So... `setHiddenValues(['Completed','Canceled',''])`

This is the completed function. The **only** differences are single quotes around the words `Completed` and `Canceled` (sic) and two single quotes `''`which identify "Blanks".

```
function so_53596113() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName("Project Tracker");
  var rang = sh.getDataRange();
  var filtercomplete = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().setHiddenValues(['Completed','Canceled','']).build();//Create criteria with two hidden values
  var filter = rang.getFilter() || rang.createFilter();// getFilter already available or create  a new one
  filter.setColumnFilterCriteria(3, filtercomplete);//set the criteria against Col3 (C column)
}
```

This is a valuable question. Google's documentation is non-existent and at the time of writing there are no other internet resources which cover this issue.

Credit to [DanCue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51538942/service-error-spreadsheetsline-with-setcolumnfiltercriteria), who was also researching Filters, for the idea to run the macro editor, look at *that* code and adapt it for the function.