# Boolean condition error using Filter whenTextNotEqualToAny() function in google app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to create a filter with whenTextNotEqualToAny(String[]) function in Google App Script.

[image]

However, I am experiencing an error:

> Exception: The boolean condition can not apply a non-equality check
> on text or date arguments for non-data source objects.

This is my code, and the error appears on the 5th line inside the brackets.

```
  function filtertTrackerData(range){  
      const filter = range.createFilter();
      const Filter_Criteria1 = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().whenTextNotEqualToAny(["CANCEL REQUEST BY CLIENT","CANCELLED","CANCELLED DUE TO PERMIT ISSUE","PULLOUT"]);
      const Filter_Criteria2 = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().whenTextNotEqualToAny(["CLOSED THRU DAS / JO MOBILE","CANCEL IN IBAS","CANCELLED","CANCELLED AT IBAS","CANCELLED BY SUBSCRIBER","CLOSED VIA JO MOBILE"]);
    
      filter.setColumnFilterCriteria(3,Filter_Criteria1);  //error appears here
      filter.setColumnFilterCriteria(4,Filter_Criteria2);
    
    }
```

This is the documentation of the function and the web results doesnt show any much more examples.
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/filter-criteria-builder#whenTextNotEqualToAny(String)

Comment: Given this Tanaike's answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64229022/apply-filtercriteria-whendateequaltoanydates-what-is-the-correct-form-of-t I'd suppose that the functions `whenTextEqualToAny()` and `whenTextNotEqualToAny()` are broken. They work only when the array contains only one element. I think it's a bug. But there is a workaround, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Looks like this could be the workaround

Comment: Does this answer your question? [apply FilterCriteria "whenDateEqualToAny(dates)" - What is the correct form of the date array (dates) to parse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64229022/apply-filtercriteria-whendateequaltoanydates-what-is-the-correct-form-of-t)

Comment: I looked at the suggestion but it seems like it is only applicable to dates. I've tried using a similar approach with the logic in mind. But the filters I am using are multiple strings, not dates nor numeric.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the behavior I want as a result is through hiddenValues.

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51457273/14475293

My code in reference to the link above:

```
function filterTrackerData(range){  
  const colStatusInput   = sheet.getRange("StatusInput").getColumn();
  const colRemarksInput  = sheet.getRange("RemarksInput").getColumn(); 
 
  
  const filtercriteria1 = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().setHiddenValues(["CANCEL REQUEST BY CLIENT","CANCELLED","CANCELLED DUE TO PERMIT ISSUE","PULLOUT"]).build();//used Cancelled NOT Canceled; Create criteria with two hidden values
  const filtercriteria2 = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().setHiddenValues(["CLOSED THRU DAS / JO MOBILE","CANCEL IN IBAS","CANCELLED","CANCELLED AT IBAS","CANCELLED BY SUBSCRIBER","CLOSED VIA JO MOBILE"]).build();

  const filter = range.getFilter() || range.createFilter();
  filter.setColumnFilterCriteria(colStatusInput, filtercriteria1);
  filter.setColumnFilterCriteria(colRemarksInput, filtercriteria2);
}
```

[image]